# vector derivative of vector summation

Tags: optimization

Want to find,
$$ \frac{d}{dV} \sum_{k=1}^{n} {V_{k}}^{2} $$

Where $V$ is a $n$-dimensional vector.

Is following correct? If not then what is the answer?

Let $$ V = [v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}, \dots , v_{n}]$$

$$ \frac{d}{dV} \sum_{k=1}^{n} {V_{k}}^{2} = [2v_{1}, 2v_{2}, 2v_{3}, \dots , 2 v_{n}]$$

Comment: correct. your summation index should start from $0$ and the vector is of dimension $n+1$, or first element should be $v_1$

Comment: Correction in vector index made in the question. Thank you @gunes

Comment: I assume that by $\frac{d}{dV}$ you mean the gradient operator?

Comment: @NDewolf : it is one part of the optimization, so yes it is a gradient operator.

Comment: Then yes, as @gunes said, it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative is correct as mentioned in the comments.